# RabbitMQ - What takes precedence, Message TTL for Queues or Per-Message TTL in Publishers

Tags: rabbitmq

If I have created a queue via Queue Declaration:

```
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
args.Add("x-message-ttl", 60000);
model.QueueDeclare("myqueue", false, false, false, args);
```

and then I published to this queue:

```
byte[] messageBodyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, world!");

IBasicProperties props = model.CreateBasicProperties();
props.ContentType = "text/plain";
props.DeliveryMode = 2;
props.Expiration = "30000";

model.BasicPublish(exchangeName,
                   routingKey, props,
                   messageBodyBytes);
```

Does the message have 60000 seconds or 30000 TTL please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per rabbitmq official [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html)

When both a per-queue and a per-message TTL are specified, **the lower value** between the two will be chosen.

So in your case it is: **30000**

Additional info:

> Queues that had a per-message TTL applied to them retroactively (when
> they already had messages) will discard the messages when specific
> events occur. Only when expired messages reach the head of a queue
> will they actually be discarded (or dead-lettered). Consumers will not
> have expired messages delivered to them. Keep in mind that there can
> be a natural race condition between message expiration and consumer
> delivery, e.g. a message can expire after it was written to the socket
> but before it has reached a consumer.
>
> When setting per-message TTL expired messages can queue up behind
> non-expired ones until the latter are consumed or expired. Hence
> resources used by such expired messages will not be freed, and they
> will be counted in queue statistics (e.g. the number of messages in
> the queue).
>
> When retroactively applying a per-message TTL policy, it is
> recommended to have consumers online to make sure the messages are
> discarded quicker.
>
> Given this behaviour of per-message TTL settings on existing queues,
> when the need to delete messages to free up resources arises, queue
> TTL should be used instead (or queue purging, or queue deletion).

Comment: The documents are hard for me to understand. I wish it was simpler. Thank you anyway